# how to tell joomla to use HTTP headers for caching instead of HTML meta tag

Tags: caching, joomla

I have a site in Joomla, and some pages can be cached for some period.

I see meta tags in the HTML :

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Fri, 29 Jun 2012 11:24:54 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public" />
```

But my CDN only support HTTP header caching.

```
Expires: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 11:24:54 GMT
```

How do I tell Joomla to use HTTP header for caching instead of meta tags in the response body?

Comment: Which version of Joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I decided it was best to modify the template I am using.

Instead of writing

```
$ExpStr = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
```

followed by

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="<?php echo $ExpStr ; ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public" />
```

I modified it to

```
$ExpStr = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
JResponse::allowCache(TRUE);
JResponse::setHeader( 'Expires', $ExpStr.' GMT' ,true);
```

Which seems working

I found this tip at : http://www.teachmejoomla.net/code/joomla-1.5/joomla-1.5-enabling-google-and-browser-cache.html

However, I expected some Joomla API for this with configuration of which implementation to use. Something like session in Rails (most known) and whether to keep it in a cookie or DB..